# How to make a button that teleports randomly on the website onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

At the moment I wanted to create a button that teleports randomly back and forth on my website. As I am very new to JavaScript, I did not get it right. That's why I don't have a code. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817583/button-on-website-that-appears-at-random) but it didn't help me.

Here's the Code i used:

```js
document.getElementById("button").style.margin = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
```

```html
<button id="button">Teleport</button>
```

Do you have any ideas how I could do this with HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into it too much:

```js
addEventListener('load', ()=>{ // load
const but = document.getElementById('button'), bS = but.style, bod = document.body;
but.onclick = function(){
  let m = bod.getBoundingClientRect(), mw = m.width, mh = m.height, b = this.getBoundingClientRect(), x = Math.floor(Math.random()*mw);
  let y = Math.floor(Math.random()*mh), w = b.width, h = b.height, xw = mw-w, yh = mh-h;
  bS.top = (y > yh ? yh : y)+'px';
  bS.left = (x > xw ? xw : x)+'px';
}
});// end load
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;
}
body{
  position:relative;
}
body>*{
  position:absolute;
}
#button{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<button id='button'>Teleport</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  var rnd = Math.random()
  var button = document.getElementById('magic');
      
  if (rnd > .25) {

    
    button.style.display = 'block'
    button.style.top = Math.random() * 100 + '%'
    button.style.left = Math.random() * 100 + '%'
  }else{
    button.style.display='none'
  }
 
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id='magic' onclick='myFunction()'>teleport</button>
```

Comment: I want the Button to teleport. Not the Math Random

Comment: despite the fact that the snippet isnt working atm, it could be simplyfied. You have an onclick event trigger added to the button. Therefor is no need to run an eventlistener as your button has a the trigger already. Also there is no reason to add and if/else statement. And you dont need to declare default `top: 0; and left: 0;`  which is the default value and will be overwritten by the JS inline style anyways.

Comment: @tacoshy, you are just wrong.  1) the snippet works fine as is. 2)there is an eventlistener  because it's needed to teleport the button on load. 3) the myFunction on the button is not defined but may be used for some other action. 3) the if else is needed to reset the display

Comment: then how do you explain that your snippet displays an error message? There was no requirement to let the button jump during laod just after a button press. So no reason for an eventlistener. Also there is no reason to hide the button and therefor no reason to give an if/else statement.

Comment: To clarify the error on the snippet is `Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined` which makes sense because you have an onclick that references a non-existent function.

Comment: @Chris and sometimes that the buttons is not displayed so that you cant even press it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.random() * 101` to randomly generate a number of  `0` - `100`. I generate 2 numbers for the y and the x axis. That way I change the position for top and left according to randomly generated number

```js
function jump() {
  var x = Math.round((Math.random() * 101)) + "%",
      y = Math.round((Math.random() * 101)) + "%";
  document.getElementById("jump").style.left = x;
  document.getElementById("jump").style.top = y;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.button-container {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100vw - 100px);
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
  <button id="jump" onclick="jump()">Click Me</button>
</div>
```